# Usage of comparison operator after assigning variable

Tags: php, variables, syntax, comparison-operators

I've seen comparison operators used straight after assigning values to variables in codes such as this:

```
($i = array_search($v, $b)) !== false // If $v is not in array, outputs false
```

Or something like this:

```
$n = 5 <= 5;
echo $n; // Outputs 1;
```

In the first example, does the comparison operator directly compare the value to array_search(...) or does it compare it to $i, since both of them are in brackets? Would it make a difference if there were no brackets around "$i = array_search(...)?

I've tried looking in the PHP manual on comparison operators, but it does not seem to mention using comparison operators in this way.

Also, in the second example, if there are no brackets, is the comparison operator comparing the value to 5 or to $n?

Could someone please link any documents or articles relating to the usage of comparison operators after assigning variables?

Comment: In the first example it compares it to whatever the expression `($i = array_search($v, $b))` evaluates to, which in this case is just `$i` (Also see: http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.precedence.php as general reference).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> does the comparison operator directly compare the value to `array_search(...)` or does it compare it to `$i`

It assigns the value from `array_search` to `$i` first, and then evaluates a comparison to that value second.

---

In your example, `array_search` will return `false` on failure.

```
if( ($i = array_search($v, $b)) !== false ){}
```

Is totally equivalent to:

```
$i = array_search($v, $b);
if($i !== false){}
```

Or:

```
if( array_search($v, $b) !== false ){}
```

It's just a convenient shortcut to also assigning the value of `$i` for use later.

Comment: @WeavingBird1917 Yes they are. How an expression is evaluated is depending on the operator precedence.

Comment: It would have the same effect, but it would change the order of operations because like [FOIL method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FOIL_method), what's inside the parenthesis gets evaluated first (assignment in this case), then outside. But without them, according to [the docs on operator precedence](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.precedence.php), comparison is evaluated before assignment.